# SSL Secured and Non-Secured Items - Wordpress

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I've setup a site for a client with an SSL Certificate. Everything works fine in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and Safari. All of them check out, and all of them have the locked symbols, green success messages, and the like. That's all fine and dandy until I get to Mobile browsers, and Internet Explorer (6 specifically, and others).

[image]

I'm using the following specs:

- PHP 5
- Wordpress 3.+ (Latest)

I've done the following:

- Used ob_start() to enclose all the contents of the pages, and forced everything to have an HTTPS prefix.
- Downloaded Fiddler to take a peak at the HTTP requests, but I can't get a good read on what exactly is wrong.
- I downloaded a couple plugins to force SSL on the site. I also changed the SiteURL to include https://.

A question comes to mind.. Can an embedded Youtube video cause this error? If so, I removed the Youtube embedded video, and I still got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your checklist of things to verify:

1. All loaded assets, such as images, scripts, css, favicons, etc. must be relative paths or be HTTPS.
2. All iframes must point to an actual page (relative or HTTPS). No SRC attribute, or an SRC of # or about:blank will raise the error. Some people have used javascript: false; with success.
3. Make sure all requests from your page are HTTPS. Google Analytics and other 3rd-party tools often have a special link you can use for HTTPS.
4. The codebase attribute of an object (Flash, Applets, etc) must be HTTPS. IE doesn’t actually make a request on this, but it does check the protocol for some reason.
5. Anything that returns an HTTP error will cause the error to pop up, since IE considers its error pages to be "insecure".
6. If you have a JavaScript that calls removeChild() on a node that has a background image, it may cause this error. You can set outerHTML = '' instead without consequence.

Things that you don’t have to worry about:

- DOCTYPES
- XHTML namespaces
- Links in the page (anchors, not the link element)

Comment: You can look at all of this data in Fiddler, by the way. Ignore all CONNECTS. They don't matter.

Comment: I've been able to get rid of all the mobile site access issues, but IE now persists with the Yes/No, this site contains Secure and Non-secure items box. Which is better than before. Thank you for a concise and direct list like that. That's what I was looking for.